# Who is using my maven artifact?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, nexus

I have a system consisting of multiple web applications (war) and libraries (jar). All of them are using maven and are under my control (source code, built artifacts in Nexus,...). Let say that application A is using library L1 directly and L2 indirectly (it is used from L1). I can easily check the dependency tree top-down from the application, using maven's dependency:tree or graph:project plugins. But how can I check, who's using my library? From my example, I want to know, whether A is the only application (or library) using L1 and that L2 is used from L1 and from some other application, let say B. Is there any plugin for maven or nexus or should I try to write some script for that? What are your suggestions?

Comment: This would be very useful, I needed this functionality many times :-) Alas, I don't believe such a thing could exist. Maybe some tool that scans the projects in your workspace, but how possible could it know what projects, living their own lives outside of your domain, are using it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to achieve this on a repository level, Apache Archiva has a "used by" feature listed under project information

[image: See screenshot].

This is similar to what mvnrepository.com lists under its "used by" section of an artifact description.

Unfortunately, Nexus does not seem to provide an equivalent feature.

Now I suppose it would be a hassle to maintain yet another repository just for that, but then it would probably easier than what some other answers suggestions, such as writing a plugin to Nexus. I believe Archiva can be configured to proxy other repositories.

**Update**

In fact, there's also a [plugin for Nexus](https://github.com/saleemshafi/nexus-artifact-usage-plugin) to achieve the "used by" feature.

Comment: +1: This is exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately not for Nexus.

Comment: This plugin does not support Nexus 3+, sad

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know nothing along these lines exists as an open source tool. You could write a Nexus plugin that traverses a repo and checks for usages of your component in all other components by iterating through all the pom's and analyzing them. This would be a rather heavy task to run though since it would have to look at all components and parse all the poms.

In a similar fashion you could do it on a local repository with some other tool. However it probably makes more sense to parse the contents of a repo manager rather than a local repository.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a Maven way to do this. That being said, there are ways of doing this or similar things. Here's a handful examples:

- Open up your projects in your favorite IDE. For instance Eclipse will help you with impact analysis on a class level, which most of the time might be good enough
- Use a simple "`grep`" on your source directory. This sounds a bit brusk (as well as stating the obvious), perhaps, but we've used this a lot
- Use dependency analysis tools such as Sonargraph or Lattix

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any public libraries for this job, so I wrote a customized app which does it for me. 
I work with a distribution which involves more than 70 artifacts bundled together. Many times after modifying an artifact, I want to ensure changes are backward compatible (i.e. no compilation errors are introduced in dependent artifacts). To achieve this, it was crucial to know all dependents of modified artifact.

Hence, I wrote an app which scans through all artifacts under a directory(/subdirectories), extracts their pom.xml and searches (in dependency section of pom) for occurrence of modified artifact. 
(I did this in java although shell/windows script can do this even more compactly.)

I'll be happy to share code on github, if that could be of any help.

Comment: That would be great idea!

Comment: @Kojotak - Code is hosted at git location: https://github.com/ShrutiTiwari/artifacto
Main class: JarInspector. The main() method finds all artifacts depending on "junit" and "aether" in "apache-maven-3.0.4" library.
Its tested on windows (hopefully it will work on linux as-is). The approach has one shortcoming though - doesn't catch transitive dependencies.

Comment: Hey Kojotak! did you find the gitcode useful for the purpose (Let me know if you get stuck while using it). I've modified it to accept commandline-arg inputs eg. to check maven-distribtution-library-artifacts depending on junit, command will be:  java -jar artifacto-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  C:\software\installation\build-tools\apache-maven-3.0.4\lib  junit

Answer (score 2):

One way that might suit your needs are to create a master-pom with all your maven projects. Then you run the following command on the master-pom:

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependency.graphml
```

Open the generated file in yEd.

Used the instructions found here:
http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/04/12/a-visual-maven-dependency-tree-view/

Comment: I've tried master pom dependant only on applications, but since they are packed as war, the transitive dependencies on libraries (jars) weren't included. I cannot simply create one master pom dependant on all projects (apps and libs), since different versions of the same library is used by different applications and have different dependencies.

Comment: I ran the maven command succesfully. But, I am getting exception when attempting to open outputFile in yed: 
yEd has encountered the following error: Could not import file dependency.graphml.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:251)

Answer (score 1):

More interesting is probably: what would you do with this information? Inform the developers of A not to use library L1 or L2 anymore, because it has a critical bug?
In my opinion you should be able to create a blacklist of dependencies/parents/plugins on your repository manager. Once a project tries to deploy/upload itself with a blacklisted artifact, it should fail. I'm saying `uploading` and not `downloading`, because that might break a lot of projects. As far as I know, this is not yet available for any repository-manager.

Comment: Sonatype CLM makes exactly that possible with the integration of Nexus staging and the CLM policies. It also has integration with Jenkins/Hudson and Eclipse so you can fails builds or as a developer inspect your components..

Comment: I was aware of the possibilities with extensions, but not the ready-to-use solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would use this information for refactoring and testing. If I've fixed some bug in one library, which application should be tested? If one library (or method/class/package from library) gets obsolete, which applications (and other libraries) should be refactored? Yes, there are unit and integration tests to catch the biggest incompatible changes, but they are not always enough.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to approach this problem is outside Java itself : write an OS-level monitoring script that tracks each case of fopen() on the jar file under question! Assuming this is in a corporate environemnt, you might have to wait for a few weeks (!) to allow all using processes to access the library at least once!

On Windows, you might use Sysinternals Process Monitor to do this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

On Unix variants, you would use DTrace or strace.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO and also from my experience, looking for a technical solution for such a problem is often an overkill. If the reason why you want to know who is using your artifact(library) is because you want to ensure backward compatibility when you change an artifact or something similar, I think it is best done by communicating your changes using traditional channels and also encourage other teams who might be using your library to talk about it (project blogs, wiki, email, a well known location where documentations are put, Jour fixe etc.).

In theory, you could write a script that crawls though each project in your repository and then parses the maven build.xml (assuming they all use maven) and see whether they have defined a dependency to your artifact. If all the projects in your organization follows the standard maven structure, it should be easy to write one such script (though if any of those projects have a dependency to your artifact via a transitive dependency, things can get a bit more tricky).